# optimal schema for user permission management

Tags: laravel, permissions, schema

So i have some hardcoded persmissions. Class "A" user can create roles and define access level for each module. When users tries to access a resource system checks if users should be able to read resource and if 'edit' controlls should be displayed.

I'm making a Laravel app, so I'm going to use this also in custom `Route::filter`.

What I was thinking of is adding `$table->integer('resource_title')` column to roles table, where:

```
0 - no access to resource
1 - user level access (read and/or basic functionality)
2 - manage level access (define/edit/delete classifiactors and/or entities)
```

What would pros do? This? Some extra pivot or `$table->boolean('resource_title_access_level')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mor flexability you can define access not only for resource but on certain actions on it.
As many roles as u wish.
For example if we have forum:

```
post
post_edit_own
post_edit
post_delete_own
post_delete
thread_create
thread_edit_own
thread_edit
thread_delete
category_create
category_edit
category_merge
category_delete
```

You even can store all of user's permissions in **ONE** field of its table.
`users`.`permissions` BIGINT

For doing this you should store this perms in some config like "bitfields" (bad english)

```
$bf = [
    post_create => 1,
    post_edit_own => 2,
    post_edit => 4,
    post_delete_own => 8,
    post_delete => 16,
    thread_create => 32,
    thread_edit_own => 64,
    thread_edit => 128,
    thread_delete => 256,
    category_create => 512,
    category_edit => 1024,
    category_merge => 2048,
    category_delete => 4096,
]
```

After that you can calculate any needed set of permissions in this manner:

```
function getPermsSet(array $permsToAdd = ['post_create', 'thread_create']) {
    $permSet = 0;
    foreach ($permsToAdd as $premission) {
        $permSet += $bf[$premission];   
    }
    return $permSet;
}
```

for example if you want to change user permissions.

```
"UPDATE users SET permissions = " . getPermSet([some permissions...]). " WHERE id = ?"
```

Check user accessabity is too easy:

```
function hasPermission($permission) {
    return  $this->permissions & $bf[$permission];
}
```

And use it like this:

```
if ($user->hasPermission('post_edit') OR 
    $user->hasPermission('post_edit_own') AND $post->author->id == $user->id
) {
    //do things related to post-edition
}
```

To get users with some permission you can use this

`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE permissions & {$bf['category_delete']}"` //somth near "Admin"

For example you can give users some specific permissions with their progress (like here on StackOverflow).

And so on. Very flexible.

Sorry for english, "pseudo-code" and almost no relation to Laravel, just variant how to organise permissions-system.
If you are interested i'll give some advices about this in exactly Laravel, little later.